# Listening to the physical menu button click

Tags: android

I am developing the application inwhich I want to listen to the long press or only press the physical menu button. I can listen this event in the activity but I want to listen it when my 
application is closed. 
  On this action I want to send message to the server. 
  I know I need to use Broadcast receiver to receive this acion and use service to send message to server.But how can I receive the menu button(physical) in brodcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            doSomething();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

Comment: As the above mrthod is in the activity. But I am looking to receive the physical home button click in the broadcast receiver ...